# Where's the FPS in chrome's FPS meter?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

We have the following UI:
[image: fps?]

I don't see an FPS figure anywhere.

(Using Chrome 85.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been removed in favor for the new design. See https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1124189&q=fps%20meter&can=1

Comment: Ah. More typical chrome idiocy. A setting called "FPS meter" does not show the one thing it's *named after*. And they have the gall to say it isn't a bug.